# Understanding the wikipedia walkthrough of the forward-backward algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I am trying to understand the walkthrough example of the forwards-backwards algorithm on wikipedia and I am failing some basic linear algebra I think.

In this figure:

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e583b98c2e440a22ac249f81d24bce3e60a13e4d

They have a dot-like symbol where they combine the two row vectors to get a new row vector of the same dimension. How do they accomplish this? That is not a valid dot product as far as I know.

Comment: It looks like they took a product of corresponding entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is component-wise or element-wise vector product, also known as the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)): $\mathbf{u}\circ \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{x}$ has $\mathbf{x}_k = \mathbf{u}_k\cdot \mathbf{v}_k$.

While the Hadamard product is technically for matrices, many techniques treat vectors as matrices - a column vector is simply a vector represented as a 1-column matrix, for instance.